# She seems to be sleeping. VS She seems sleeping. (What's the difference?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> She seems to be sleeping.

> She seems sleeping.

What's the difference? My question will be as you see: what's the function of 'to be'?

Previous knowledge: 'to infitive' is used to imply a 'future' event like 'something is to happen'

EDIT:

> She seems to be happy

> She seems happy.

Question is the same: What's the function of "to be"?

Answer (score 3):

The first one is correct; *sleeping* is the participle form of the verb. We use the infinitive *to be* after *seem.*

We can use the participle like an adjective (the sleeping woman), but it is not idiomatic to say *she seems sleeping.*

Comment: Thx. Kate. Please see the EDIT ver. of the question.

Comment: "She seems to be happy" is the more 'correct' version. For some reason I can't explain, it is idiomatic in colloquial speech to use _seem_ followed directly by an adjective, but not by a verb participle.